# Put movable circle over google map and get center position and radius

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I would like to put in my map on site something similar like on this [site](http://www.apartmentfinder.com/Georgia/Atlanta-Apartments)

[image]

When choose Personalize Your Search, I need to get gps of circle center and zoom and radius.

How could I achieve this?

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [Google Maps API V3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/), then you have the [google.maps.Circle class](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Circle).  The circle gives you all the information you are requesting through it's methods:

- getRadius()
- getCenter()

It also has events, so that you can listen to mouse clicks on your map and move the circle to that click.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you add a [draggable marker](http://code.google.com/intl/el/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Markers) to you map?And the [icon of the marker](http://code.google.com/intl/el/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Icons) can be an icon with a circle around it.

Answer (score 1):

Thats how you can make a draggable element using Jquery, but not quite sure about getting a GPS location.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Answer (score 1):

You can then find out the latitude, longitude when mouse moves over map. These lat and long info with help you to geocode the address and you can play around once you have current longitude and latitude information.